# Do Catholics have a "profession of faith" in Jesus Christ before baptism?

Tags: catholicism, catholic-catechism

I was looking through one of the older catechism books and I seem to recall it mentioning that a profession of faith in Jesus generally precedes a baptism.  Is this true?

Comment: Do you mean a personal profession of faith made by the person being baptised?

Comment: You are probably looking for the Apostles' Creed.

Answer (score 3):

Do Catholics have a “profession of faith” in Jesus Christ before baptism in older catechisms?

The short answer is **yes**.

The [Baltimore Catechism](http://www.baltimore-catechism.com/lesson14.htm) states:

> Q. 647. What are the chief ceremonies used in solemn baptism, and what do they signify?
>
> A. The chief ceremonies used in solemn baptism are:
>
> 1. **A profession of faith** and renouncement of the devil to signify our worthiness;
> 2. The placing of salt in the mouth to signify the wisdom imparted by faith;
> 3. The holding of the priest's stole to signify our reception into the Church;
> 4. The anointing to signify the strength given by the Sacrament;
> 5. The giving of the white garment or cloth to signify our sinless state after baptism; and
> 6. The giving of the lighted candle to signify the light of faith and fire of love that should dwell in our souls.

Comment: If you want to add to this, the current RCIA includes three scrutinies that preceed baptism.  One of them is the presentation of the Nicene Creed which is commited to memory and   declared aloud.  This is "a profession of faith and belief," from credo meaning "I believe"  ... however, I will caveat that with how the USCCB requires things.